# Getting error message while following Revit Design Automation tutorial

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am following Autodesk Forge Design Automation tutorial for Revit from [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/).
I completed all steps but the last 7th step returns follwoing error -

```
{
"appbundles": [
    "The App V0XRbvF7fj6glAh1PFwcG0s2680gZmTL.DeleteWallsApp+test could not be found\nParameter name: appbundles"
]}
```

Can anyone please let me know if there is somthing missing that I should consider? I would appreciate if  there is a better example tutorial available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what [Jeremy Farand-Belanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11057009/jeremy-farand-belanger) said:

- according to the tutorial you should be using a [nickname](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/forgeapps-id-PATCH) to reference your appbundles, but in your example you're using the Forge app client ID; if you had created a nickname in one of the previous steps, make sure to use that name in all subsequent calls
- if you're using Visual Studio Code, we're maintaining an extension that allows you to browse various Forge services and content, including Design Automation: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools; you could use it to browse your Design Automation appbundles, activities, etc.
- if you're still unable to initiate your work item, please send us more details about the requests you're making to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` and we will investigate the issue further

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems like you might have missed a step (Or something went wrong in one of the step) of task 4 (Upload an AppBundle).
I would review task 4 to make sure you correctly executed the following steps:

1. Register the AppBundle
2. Upload the AppBundle
3. Create an alias for the AppBundle

To validate that your appBundle was setup correctly, you can:

1. Validate that you can see
   "V0XRbvF7fj6glAh1PFwcG0s2680gZmTL.DeleteWallsApp+test" in the list
   of available AppBundle when executing this request
   https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/appbundles-GET/
2. Validate that you can download the expected appBundle from the
   package url you can retrieve with this request (note that this can
   only be done by the owner of the AppBundle):
   https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/appbundles-id-GET/